Did the Turkish defense industry ever receive any significant foreign investment from any other OECD country?
I am curious about foreign investment in the Turkish defense industry.
Did the Turkish defense industry ever receive any significant foreign investment from any other OECD country?

Does the fact that the Bayraktars etc. were made with many Western parts count? FDI is not the only measure of interdependence. BTW, in order to bypass Western sanctions, they sales were sometimes made from South African subsidiaries https://www.reuters.com/world/western-firms-have-supplied-critical-components-turkish-drones-2023-10-10/

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever, Does the fact that the Bayraktars etc. were made with many Western parts count? --- no. That is not investment. That is import by Turkey.

What do you mean by "foreign investment"? Technically, that would be Western countries buying (fully or partially) Turkish defense industries. Western countries buying Turkish military hardware is not an "investment". And Western countries may occasionally help their own domestic industries but they do not go buying foreign military industries.

@SJuan76, https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/foreign-investment.asp

Not exactly responsive to the question, but Turkey developed its defense industry for much the same reasons that Iran, Israel, North Korea, and South Africa did. It was subject to international sanctions for an extended period of time that prevented it from importing weapons so it had to develop its own home grown defense industry. Any international assistance may have had to be covert for that reason.

Turkey does not appear to report such data even e.g. in 95-pages long reports on FDI meaning they don't break down manufacturing on items as specific as defense [industry]. OTOH "other manufacturing" accounts for about half of the FDI in manufacturing in Turkey.

Likewise the 40-page FDI attraction strategy (for 2024-2028) doesn't exactly break this down, but at least mention defense...

Knowledge-intensive investments that enhance the
value-addition in the country are considered as ‘Quality
FDI’ projects for Türkiye. In the last 10 years, Türkiye has
attracted 357 FDI projects under this profile.
Manufacturing investments in high-tech sectors with significant
potential for job creation in STEM fields (aviation, ICT, medical
devices, pharmaceuticals, semiconductors, software, and
information technology services, aerospace and defense, etc.)

In a number of sectors including aviation, Turkish laws prohibit foreign investors from owning more than 50% of a company. While that piece doesn't mention the defense industry as such, one might venture a guess similar rules apply to anything strategic enough. So, any FDI would probably be a minority share in such industries, in Turkey.
I was able to find a piece of (quasi-official AA) news that an Indian firm bought a 30% share in a (smaller) Turkish drone/UAV maker. It's not too clear to me how much of that is for military purposes, but the piece does mention that the deal was apparently signed (or at least announced) at the  International Defense Industries Fair. So, these deals are not completely absent.
OTOH for much less trivial examples focused on defense, I found another Turkish government publication...

1988: FNSS, a joint venture
owned 51% by Nurol
Holding and 49% by BAE
Systems, is a leading
manufacturer and
supplier of tracked and
wheeled armored
vehicles and weapon
systems for the Turkish
and Allied Armed Forces.
2010: Kale Pratt & Whitney, a
joint venture owned 51%
by Kale Group and 49% by
Pratt & Whitney, use stateof-the-art technologies
critical to the production
of the F135 engine
powering the F-35
Lightning II fighter
aircraft.

Although the F-35 deal with Turkey was pretty much cancelled, it was replaced by the Kaan which involves (older) Western engines, and the financial part of the deal seems similar:

2017: Rolls-Royce and Kale
Group, established a
joint venture company
owned 51% by Kale and
49% by Rolls-Royce,
to develop aircraft engines
for Türkiye, initially
targeting the TF-X National
Fighter Jet Project.

A couple more examples (not sure if the T129 fits the FDI profile though):

European companies are active in the making of
key Turkish defence products. Most notably, since 2009
the Italian giant Leonardo through its subsidiary Agusta
Westland is a partner of TAI in the production of the T129
ATAK Multirole Combat helicopter. [...]
The third type of interaction is European companies’
subsidiaries in Turkey. Here, an example is the
establishment of RBSS in 2016 by the Turkish BMC (51%),
the German Rheinmetall AG (39%)  and the Malaysian Etika
Strategi (10%).

Probably somehwat similar to the T129 is the T70 with Sikorsky. It's hard find any financial % details, but there are parts sharing details, e.g.

Within the scope of the Program, TEI, the Engine Subcontractor, will be responsible for the production of 60 different components corresponding to roughly 58% of the T700 engine, engine assembly, final testing, qualification and configuration management. Hot spot parts such as the engine's combustion chamber are manufactured by TEI.

TAI itself is 100% owned by Turkish (mostly state) owners, but it doesn't seem to make any engines, whereas TEI does, but the latter is a joint venture (of TAI - 50.5%) with GE (46.2%). To quote from GE's blurb on the importance of this collaboration:

TEI is one of the largest producers of parts for F110 engines, as well as licensed MRO facility not only for Türkiye but also for several countries for GE’s T700 used in Black Hawk, Seahawk, Super Cobra and Apache helicopters, and GE’s F110 engine, used in F16 and F15 fighter aircrafts and GE’s LM2500 gas turbines, used in the Barbaros, Gabya and ISTIF class frigates (MILGEM-I), the Ada class (MILGEM) corvettes and the DIMDEG fleet oil replenishment vessel.

Interestingly enough, BMC which makes Turkey's next generation tank--the Altay (mostly with South Korean technology, in terms of foreign tech participation, after Germany pulled out) is actually a joint venture itself, but with Qatar, which bought a 49.9% share in 2014.
FWTW, in general (i.e. not specific to any sector), FDI in Turkey seems dominated by the EU with around 59% of the inflows. OTOH, in absolute numbers, FDI in Turkey appears to have been halved in the past decade.

Possibly as "investment".  Certainly as "joint venture".  Hard to be more specific than that on OECD countries without looking back quite a few years back.
UAE’s EDGE Group weighs multibillion-dollar Turkey investments

Ankara: Abu Dhabi-owned defence company EDGE Group said it’s weighing billions of dollars of investments in Turkey after it signed preliminary deals with firms, including Aselsan Elektronik Sanayi and drone-maker Baykar Teknoloji.

Now, before we go on, let's keep in mind "foreign investment" in defense firm isn't really a common thing (for national security reasons) in most countries.  Which is why I think you'll have more luck with "joint venture".
There are different time periods to consider:
Armenian Weekly (yes,yes...) The intersection between Turkey’s defense industry and its foreign policy 

From 2004 onwards, Turkey decided to abandon the joint venture model with foreign (mainly Western) partners in favor of local prime contractors to pursue indigenous products and solutions. Several homegrown solutions proved to be attractive among export customers for the following reasons.

IARI

According to an IISS report, the turning point for the transformation has been the Turkish invasion of Cyprus. Following the intervention of 1974, the US declared an embargo on arms sales to the country, a measure that in the long run forced Turkey to adapt and overcome its dependence on the NATO ally and main defence supplier.


Other geopolitical turmoil contributed to the rapprochement between Turkey and the US, the main one was the Iranian revolution. As a consequence, the nation benefited from a renewed American interest in developing a partnership that is essential for its Middle East policy. Thus, the newborn defence industries saw the access of numerous overseas capitals, which fostered and fortified its importance for both the national political and military and class, as well as NATO partners.


Finally, the return to power of Islamist parties has not undermined the liberal policies essential for economic growth. On the contrary, Turkey started a successful policy of joint ventures creation, attracting foreign capitals and expertise while maintaining production at home. Since 2002, under the leadership of Erdoğan...

The F35 (and the S400)
I am not sure about the financial arrangements of it, but Turkey was slated to be, along with Italy, the major European hub for F35 maintenance. Until the S-400 purchases.
See also Defence Turkey.
That article does seem talk $, but it could be "just sales", rather than "investment".

As of today, we have long term contracts with our customers, mainly with our partner General Electric (GE) totally at an amount of 1,6 billion USD until 2013.

Still, though it's unclear, I kinda think Turkey would have had to receive some money upfront to support ramping up to the F35 maintenance requirements.
The S400 purchase dates back to 2017 and I figure you need to look at timelines before that to see much other Western/OECD interest in deep partnerships with Turkey's defense industry.
Erdogan's first PMship - 2003 - wasn't necessarily a watershed.  IIRC the West was looking towards the arrival of a regular democracy that happened to be Muslim.  Things soured later on for various reasons, but good vibes persisted for a while.
And yet another time slice comes from Ukrainian-Turkish defence collaborations since 2022 but I am unsure Ukraine has the cash to invest, rather than purchase.

UAE and Turkey have fought and probably are still fighting a proxy war in Libya. UAE mostly supplied Chinese drones to their guy. I don't see Turkey giving much of a share (certainly not a controlling one) to any UAE company. (The source for that piece also an UAE-based site.)

There might also be some Qatar envy there. Turns out the latter has 49.9% share in the company that makes Turkey's next generation tank.
